# jQuery - .outerHeight() not returning correct value

Tags: jquery

I want child-elements with `position: absolute;` to fit in their static parent. I try to apply the `.outerHeight()` value of the child-elements on their parent. 
But `.outerHeight()` seems not beeing able to catch the defined height-values inside the child-elements.

`.ft-slider` is the parent and `slides[]` holds the child-elements.

```
/* find all sliders */ 
var sliders = $(document).find(".ft-slider");

/* initialise sliders */
for (var i=0; i < sliders.length; i++) {

    /** adjust slider height to its content **/
    var slides = $( sliders[i] ).children(),
        heights = [];

    /* get heights */
    for (var j=0; j < slides.length; j++){
        heights[j] = $( slides[j] ).outerHeight(true);
    }

    /* find heighest element */
    var highest = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

    /* apply height on .ft-slider */
    $( sliders[i] ).css("height", highest);


    /** only show first slide **/
    var last = slides.length - 1;

    /* hide all slides */
    for (var k=0; k < slides.length; k++){
        $( slides[k] ).hide();
    }
    /* show current (first) slide */
    $( slides[current] ).show();
}
```

here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/slottybon/8652rjx7/8/

Comment: For easier way for us to understand your problem, please provide JSFiddle

Comment: okay, added the JSFiddle link at the bottom.

Comment: When i tested it locally, it's working with your JSFiddle. its taking the height of the highest and applies it to parent, even when they have different content and structure.

Comment: sorry, i missed the actual problem. Here you can see that it ignores height and padding of the child-element: http://jsfiddle.net/slottybon/8652rjx7/8/

Comment: O wow. It seems to work in the fiddle now... Well that should settle it then. Thanks for your help though. :)

Comment: working version: http://jsfiddle.net/slottybon/8652rjx7/9/